# Explicit deformations of pseudo representations

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, galois-representations

Let $G$ be a group (which I will be  glad to consider to be the absolute Galois group of a $p$-adic field, and so satisfies Mazur's finiteness condition which appears in his paper Deforming Galois representations).

Several people have studied the deformation theory of residual continuous representations $\rho : G \to GL_n(k)$ where $k$ is a finite field (not necessary of characteristic $p$) from an explicit viewpoint : they managed to obtain explicit equations for the universal (or versal) deformation ring and were able to prove some results about the geometry of this ring (in my knowledge, a lot of this work take place in the setting of 2 dimensional representations, I don't know if anything else has been done for representation of dimension > 2).

Does this work has also been carried out in the context of pseudo-representations (or pseudo-characters, or determinants, I don't know what is the best terminology) ? Namely, does one know if there is somewhere in the litterature an example where the ring representing the deformation functor of pseudo-representations is given by explicit equations ?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of $2$-dimensional pseudo-characters of the absolute Galois group of 
$\mathbb Q_p$, when $p\ge 5$ have been worked out in this paper:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2008.

See the appendix, and Prop. 9.12 in the scalar case. The rings there are formally smooth in all cases, except, when the character is trivial plus cyclotomic.

The idea of the proof is to identify the pseudo character ring with some deformation ring of a Galois rep via the trace map. (This is known to be an isomorphism if the residual rep is irreducible, the reducible cases are trickier.)